# Can't see IPython Console in Spyder

Tags: ipython, spyder

I have recently installed IPython in my Ubuntu 14.04 with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install spyder
```

My problem is that I cannot use the IPython console:

[image]

All I see is a gray blank area in the lower right of Spyder. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**:

1. `ipython-qtconsole` is already installed in my system so it is not the one causing the problem.

[image]

2. `python-zmq` is also already installed.

[image]

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453400/cant-get-ipython-console-in-spyder, perhaps try installing `python-zmq` ?

Comment: @edwinksl Tried it. I got the same results it is already installed.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3108) at Spyder's GitHub repo seems to describe your problem but is not resolved yet.

Comment: @edwinksl I solved the problem by upgrading to the latest lts release -> 16.04.

Comment: Great to hear the problem is resolved, although I am not exactly sure what in the upgrade process fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 and this has solved the problem. I can now see the IPython Console.

[image]